# ActivityNotFoundException when using intent to open another App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm Trying to open another application from my Activity, here is my Intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(
                    new ComponentName(
                            "com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile",
                            "com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile.views.StartActivity"
                    )
            );
            intent.putExtra("pin", "");
            String token = preferences.getString("kassatoken","");
            intent.putExtra("token",token);
            intent.putExtra("receipt_bundle",json);
            startActivity(intent);
```

But when i run this code, i get next Error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile/com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile.views.StartActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I Also tried to check if any system app can handle this intent:

```
 PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

isIntentSafe always false, but i've installed Application with package name "com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile". And this app was opened.

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` also didn't help.
What could cause this error? This code with intent was taken from official documentation of that service\app. I've already sent email to their support, but maybe something wrong with my code?

Comment: @RevathiManoharan Did your read the question? I want to launch another app. I don't have access to Manifest of that app

Answer (score 1):

**To open another app, you can use this:**

```
intent = new Intent("com.example.hasib.videoplayer.MediaPlayerActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: Insted of "com.example.hasib.videoplayer.MediaPlayerActivity" use your terget app package. This 2 line code works for me, if i's not work for you then probably problem with that app package name or your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a package name, you can use [`PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) to build an intent. For example :

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.bifit.cashdesk.mobile");
    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

If it doesn't work, you can use the [*apkanalyzer*](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer) SDK tool to extract the manifest, then look at the intent filters it contains to find out how to to build an intent to start it :

```
apkanalyzer manifest print <some_application.apk>
```